# Using fork() to run mutltiple tasks

Tags: c, fork

Trying to run 'tasks' in parallel but (obviously) I am failing miserably.

What I want it to do: split the size into 8 different (equal size) tasks and "doSomething" on them simultaneously.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include  <sys/types.h> //pid_t
void doSomething(const int start, const int end){
    printf("%d. Doing %d to %d \n", getpid(), start, end);
}

int main(){

    int word_size = 10000;

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        pid_t pid;
        pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0){
            doSomething((i)*(word_size/8), (i+1)*(word_size/8));
        }
        else {
            doSomething((i+1)*(word_size/8), (i+2)*(word_size/8));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you sure you want separate processes rather than threads?

Comment: @ChrisTurner, yes, trying to avoid pthread

Comment: Your parent process should not execute the function;  only the children should.  Don't forget to wait for the children to die before exiting.

Comment: @Space why avoiding pthreads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not really splitting it in 8 even parts. You are just starting 4 parallel processes and execute other 4 parts sequentially in the main thread. Also, you exit your main thread as soon as you done and let your parallel processes to finish at their leisure. So, in reality you would need something like the following:

```
    pid_t pid[8];
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        pid[i] = fork();
        if(pid[i] == 0){
            doSomething((i)*(word_size/8), (i+1)*(word_size/8));
            return 0;  // or exit(0);
        }
   }
```

Note that after forking, the child process should not return to the loop. I added teh `return 0;` statement to return from the `main` at this point. Or yuo can use `exit(0);` if this is not a main routing. I think that the most logical would be using `exit(0);` in the `doSomething` function.

now you have all pids of all process you started. you need to wait in the main thread till all of them finish (unless you really want to let them run on their own. Something like the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
     int status;
     waitpid(pid[i], &status, WNOHANG);
}
```

Comment: possibly need to do something if `fork` returns -1, like break out of the loop? Or at least, not call `waitpid` for any failed children.

Comment: @Serge, thanks for the comment. However, it appears this doesn't work either. Basically, I get a lot of processes, repeating the same work. 

Result: https://pastebin.com/9g5Qy3CL

Comment: You would need to make sure that your `doSomething` does not return, but exits. Or you can do it directly in the loop. I will edit the answer.

Comment: Like adding exit(0) after the call to doSomething? Going to try that!

Answer (score 0):

According to your logic, you would be able to cover only till 5000 words (according to your wordsize of 1000) even though you will have 8 duplicate processes running.

I suppose you want help with the logic. A bit tweak of your for loop would do the trick :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include  <sys/types.h> //pid_t
void doSomething(const int start, const int end){
    printf("%d. Doing %d to %d \n", getpid(), start, end);
}

int main(){

    int word_size = 10000;

    for(int i=0; i<=6; i=i+2){        //the tweaks
        pid_t pid;
        pid = fork();
        if(pid == 0){
            doSomething((i)*(word_size/8), (i+1)*(word_size/8));
        }
        else {
            doSomething((i+1)*(word_size/8), (i+2)*(word_size/8));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps